# How to check if the user logs in with google, And if it is so directed directly to an activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm doing an activity where you log in with google, everything I have is fine but I need to check if the user is already logged in and so direct me to the "MainActivity"

the relevant code:

```
  private void initLogInWithGoogle(){
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();



}

private void sigInGoogle(){
Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApi);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}

private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result){

    if(result.isSuccess()){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);

    }
}


     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check authentication provider by using  user.getProviders().get(0) ;  which will return login provider.  Use this in AuthStateListener  in if user!=null.

Comment: how can i did this?

Comment: Write this in AuthStateListener method in if (user!=null)  This will return  provider details , it is use to check which provider your user is using,  Ex:  it will return google if user try to login using google account.

Comment: doesnt works =(, i try if(FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser != null){Intent ...}

Comment: Did you write AuthStateListener  in onCreate() of your activity?

Comment: i read your code ,you are missing some piece of code . if google signin was successful then authenticate it with firebase i.e get OAuth  token . write this    in if(result.isSuccess()){  } .   ' GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount(); firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account); '    . this will generate OAuth token and  the auth state listener will be notified i.e firebase will came to know that user is not null in AuthstateListener() . After that check provider .

Comment: the method 'firebaseAuthWithGoogle();' doesnt shows

Comment: You need to write it first. See example code given by firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin. This will help you alot.

Comment: thanks i added this and i added if(user!= null ){ goto ...} but doesnt works

Comment: Did you follow the complete steps suggested in firebase example?  What went wrong ,does user is not sign in?

Comment: If everything is fine, and follow all the steps, but exiting the app is still on the home screen instead of going directly to another activity

Comment: Make a log and check whether  auth state is changing after user log in

Comment: how can i did this? sorry im new in this

Comment: Mark it as best answers... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, You can use AuthListener

declare AuthListener :

```
    // [START declare_auth_listener]
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth_listener]

   // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]
```

put it also in OnStart and OnStop :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

then check using this :

```
// [START auth_state_listener]
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {   
                    // User is signed in        
                    //redirect
                    Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this , HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };
 // [END auth_state_listener]
```

Comment: sorry , i update it. i forget to put the mAuth declaration